# How to create a new Rust project from the VS Code, and not through the command-line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

The Rust Programming Language book explains [how to create a project on the command-line](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch01-03-hello-cargo.html). The same section is referred by the explanation of [how to Quickstart using the extension of the VS Code for Rust](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust).

How can I create a new Rust project from within VS Code, and not through the command-line?

Comment: It is hard to tell what is a project. For example, it is possible to have a set of rust files, compile them using `Rustc` (compiler) and call it a project. What people usually do is use the `Cargo` layout, which is a `Cargo.toml` and `src/(main|lib).rs` file.

Comment: The post is about whether it's possible to create a Rust project from the VS Code. But sure, I was thinking about how to create the project as described by The Rust Programming Language book at https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch01-03-hello-cargo.html. At the time of making the post, I was not aware of what you say by "it is possible to have a set of rust files, compile them using Rustc (compiler) and call it a project."

Comment: *Why*? Does something prevent you from opening the command line and typing `cargo new`?

Comment: @Shepmaster, No nothing, Just curious whether it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

[This extension](https://github.com/panicbit/vscode-cargo) has `cargo new` command as their planned feature.

You can write your own extension for simple tasks like this, it's quite easy to write one.(I wrote before) But it's still overkill two create a directory(src) and 2 files (main.rs,cargo.toml).

You can create files/folder manually with `new file` button and add a snippet for each boilerplate code in the files. Snippets can take parameters, you can give your project name there.

If you are going to use this feature a lot, you can write a global task, that can create and populate those files for you.

In the `source control` pane, when you click the icon near `SOURCE CONTROL` title, it will create a `.git` folder for you, which is also done by `cargo new`.

If you are looking to specifically create a project with the Rust official extension, it's language server and it doesn't have that functionality.